# Does c/c++/java/PHP have closure?

Tags: java, php, c++, c, closures

So far I only see closure in javascript:

```
var name=...;

$(..).onclick(function() {
     //here I can reference to name
});
```

Does this feature exist in `c/c++/java/PHP`?

If exists,one hello world example available?

Comment: Your example is not quite a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_\(computer_science\)).

Comment: What you're talking about are called lambda functions. Closure means something else.

Comment: @Gumbo, looks like a closure to me. Granted the `onclick` bit is irrelevant, although the anonymous function will indeed close over the scope, including `name` like the OP described. What's your quarrel?

Comment: @davin: Unless the function doesn’t reference a variable that is not in its local scope, it isn’t a closure. But now I see that his comment denotes a reference to the outer `name`. :)

Comment: @Gumbo, not sure what you mean. Even in that case, it would still be a closure, just that the function wouldn't be utilising its closure characteristic, and the example wouldn't be a very helpful one, although it would still be correct. Implementation specifics aside, every function expression in javascript is a closure.

Answer (score 2):

As for PHP, you can enable access to a specific variable inside a closure method like this:

```
$xVar = "var";

$closure = function() use ($xVar) {
    echo $xVar;
}

$closure();
```

And it's also possible to alter this variable inside the closure:

```
$xVar = "var";

$closure = function($newVar) use (&$xVar) {
   $xVar = $newVar;
}

$closure("new var content");
```

Answer (score 1):

C no, as functions aren't first-class objects.
C++ not *yet*, but it does with the upcoming standard (commonly referred to as C++0x), with so called lambda expressions:

```
std::string name;
auto mylambda = [&](){ std::cout << name; };
//               ^ automatically reference all objects in the enclosing scope.
```

Comment: what do you mean by first class objects?

Comment: @compile-fan: It means you can't create them *on-the-fly*, like you can create an `int` or a `struct`. Functions must all be known at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

[C++11](http://www.weiqigao.com/blog/2008/03/30/closures_comes_to_c0x.html) has closures, as does [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).  Im not sure about Java.

Answer (score 1):

At one point, closures (Project Lambda) were going to be part of Java 7, but they are currently listed as ["Deferred to Java 8 or later"](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/#deferred).

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29#PHP

For PHP

```
<?php
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};

$greet('World');
$greet('PHP');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has those too, since 5.3. They're not as flexible (in that you can't use `$this`), but still very useful.

Lisp and its dialects also have closures.

Answer (score 0):

For C, they are available as a non-standard extension called [blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29).